# IF block statement in inside an execlineb script

Tags: bash, docker, sh, busybox, alpine-mail

I have a Docker Container based on Alpine which runs [S6 Overlay](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay) to manage two services inside it (a music DB, and a web interface to manage it). The problem is that the second service is optional, and it depends on the `${SERVICE_2}` environment variable (true|false).

So, basically I have this, but the service cannot run because the `if` block is not valid:

```
#!/usr/bin/execlineb -P

with-contenv

if [ $SERVICE_2 = true ]; then \
    sh -c "exec -a service_2 /usr/bin/php /var/www/service_2_music_admin_script.php >> /proc/self/fd/1 2>&1" \
;fi
```

Executing the script returns:

```
if: fatal: unterminated block
```

By the way, the container doesn't have `bash`; it runs Busybox. I'm trying to avoid installing bash unless it's critical.

Comment: Is this syntax supported maybe: `[ $SERVICE_2 = true ] && sh …`?

Comment: No, even without line breaks `\`. Same error.

Comment: I knew little about `execlineb` and assumed it is similar to `sh`, since your `if` is basically the same. But [this site](https://skarnet.org/software/execline/if.html) states a very different `if` syntax and this could be the cause of your error. Another idea: you run `sh` eventually; why won't you make this script a `sh` script in the first place?

Comment: I decided to use `sh`. Basically, I hashbanged `/usr/sbin/with-contenv sh` and proceeded normally.

Answer (score 2):

After some digging, the If block in execline became too much of a nuance. So I solved the root problem: changing to sh with container environment variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/with-contenv sh

...
```

Then I used `exec` to execute the process (otherwise it doesn't connect to S6).